# Assigning abstract val a value in sealed class

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, abstract-class, sealed-class

I've a sealed class from which a couple of abstract classes inherit from. Since there are a bunch of fields in sealed class that need to be initialized in abstract class, I'm trying to move it to the secondary constructor however secondary constructor doesn't let us declare `override val` fields to make the code a bit more concise.
The only other way I can think of is to make the fields `lateinit var` but then I loose immutability.

```
sealed class Animal {
  abstract val object1 : SomeObject
  abstract val object2 : SomeObject2
  abstract val object3 : SomeObject3
  abstract val object4 : SomeObject4
}

abstract class GrassEaterAnimal : Animal {

   //trying to do this
   constructor(override val object1 : SomeObject, override val object2 : SomeObject2, override val object3 : SomeObject3, override val object4 : SomeObject4, func : (field1, field2) -> Foo)
}
```

Is there a way to make this code cleaner or any other suggestions that can help in this situation?

Comment: You're missing the keyword 'class' after 'abstract'.

Comment: What's that last `func` parameter doing there?

Comment: Thanks. I'll add it :)

Comment: @Sweeper it's a lambda that'll be called in one of the methods in the class that extends from `GrassEaterAnimal`

Comment: And why aren't you using the primary constructor?

Comment: What if someone calls `GrassEaterAnimal`'s primary constructor? What will those fields be initialised to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement/initialize properties in the primary constructor:

```kotlin
abstract class GrassEaterAnimal(
    override val object1: SomeObject,
    override val object2: SomeObject2,
    override val object3: SomeObject3,
    override val object4: SomeObject4,
) : Animal()
```

Comment: Yes that's something I'm trying to avoid to make it look cleaner.

Comment: How is secondary constructor cleaner than primary constructor?

Comment: I've got an impression that you just don't like the syntax of primary constructors in Kotlin and you would like to avoid it by using secondary constructors. If this is the case then no, you can't easily use secondary constructors as a substitute for a primary constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions folks. Any suggestions to make it a bit cleaner by doing some `lateinit val` solution since we don't have that capability either in kotlin :/

Comment: This answer is the cleanest possible solution, and definitely cleaner than your suggested syntax in the original question. It seems you have a different concept of what "clean" means. Multiple constructors is less clean than a single primary constructor. `lateinit` is always less clean and an unfortunate necessity in certain circumstances.

Comment: @user2498079 Note that `lateinit` is worse not only because of being mutable. It requires 3 times more code. As in good old Java, for each field we need to: define a property, create a constructor parameter and assign param to a property. It doesn't sound clean to me ;-) Primary constructors in Kotlin provide shortcut syntax for doing all 3 tasks at the same time. And I don't see a way how the language could be redesigned to provide the same shortcut syntax outside of primary constructors.

Comment: Why don't you think this example looks clean? It's about as clear and concise and simple as you're going to get - you need to ``override`` some abstract properties in the parent class, and you need to specify their types for whatever's calling the constructor. You're getting all that in one definition, it's pretty neat! If this is about how it looks, going from a short one-line primary constructor to kind of a blob of code at the top of the class, I'd really encourage you to try and get over it - I felt the same way, but that's purely an aesthetic thing, and this style is very neat in its way